# A type or interface for an array with string properties

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in TypeScript to define a type or an interface for an array to accept random string properties? For example, in JavaScript we can do the following:

```
const list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
list.foo = 'bar';
console.log(a); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, foo: 'bar' ]
console.log(a[1]); // 2
console.log(a.foo); // 'bar'
```

I would like to define an interface or a type in TypeScript that allows such an array. I have tried the following:

```
interface IList extends Array<number> {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

But it generates a series of errors that existing array methods are not assignable to type string.

I can have specific keys set in that interface (e.g., `foo: string;`, but I was wondering if there is a way to allow random string properties?

Comment: Do you have a _real_ use-case for using a non-numeric index in an Array? That's super weird and kind of exactly what Objects are made for. Also note that in your above example, `list.length === 5` despite the additional `foo`, and iterators (like `map`) won't encounter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the type by using the `type` keyword and an intersection:

```
type IList = number[] & {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

But assigning a value to that type is a little tricky, since an array isn't assignable to it (since arrays lack the string index signature). To fix that, you'll have to manually cast your array to that type when you assign it:

```
const x: IList = [1, 2, 3]; // Error: Index signature missing in type number[]
const y = [1, 2, 3] as IList; // Okay
```

Then:

```
y[0] // inferred as number
y["foo"] // inferred as string
y.filter(x => x % 2); // inferred as number[]
```